# Duplicate entries in cross join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three table

Account table:

| account_id | account_key | bank_key | account_number | account_type_key | account_type_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 111 | 10001 | 1 | SAVING |
| 2 | 50 | 111 | 10002 | 2 | CURRENT |
| 3 | 60 | 222 | 10003 | 1 | SAVING |
| 4 | 70 | 333 | 10004 | 1 | SAVING |
| 5 | 70 | 333 | 10005 | 2 | CURRENT |
| 6 | 80 | 111 | 10006 | 1 | SAVING |
| 7 | 80 | 111 | 10007 | 2 | CURRENT |

Bank table:

| bank_id | bank_key | bank_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | A |
| 2 | 222 | B |
| 3 | 333 | C |

Account x Bank table:

| uniqe_id | bank_key | account_key | bank_x_account_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 50 | 901 |
| 2 | 111 | 50 | 902 |
| 3 | 222 | 60 | 903 |
| 4 | 333 | 70 | 904 |
| 5 | 333 | 70 | 905 |
| 6 | 111 | 80 | 906 |
| 7 | 111 | 80 | 907 |

I have below SP to get accounts for particular bank.

```
Select a.account_key,
         a.account_number,
         a.account_type_key,
         a.account_type_code,
         a.bank_key,
         b.bank_Name,
         axb.bank_x_account_id,
    From accounts a
    inner join account_x_bank axb on a.account_key = axb.account_key
    inner join banks b on axb.bank_key = b.bank_key
    Where a.bank_key = @bank_key
```

I have one function which provide the main account details for particular bank type.

For example: `fnGetMainAccountTypeOfBank(111)` will give below result (We have one main account per user, so this will always return one row)

| bank_key | bank_Name | account_type_key | account_type_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A | 1 | SAVING |

Now I want to modify my SP in such a way that, if I pass bank_key it should return all the accounts under it with Main account only.

For example: `GetAccountsForBank(111)`
This should give below result

| account_key | account_number | account_type_key | account_type_code | bank_key | bank_Name | bank_x_account_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 10001 | 1 | SAVING | 111 | A | 901 |
| 80 | 10006 | 1 | SAVING | 111 | A | 906 |

I tried with cross join like below,

```
Select a.account_key,
         a.account_number,
         m.account_type_key,
         m.account_type_code,
         m.bank_key,
         m.bank_Name,
         axb.bank_x_account_id,
    From accounts a
    inner join account_x_bank axb on a.account_key = axb.account_key
    cross join fnGetMainAccountTypeOfBank(a.bank_key) m 
    Where a.bank_key = @bank_key
```

but it is giving following result.

| account_key | account_number | account_type_key | account_type_code | bank_key | bank_Name | bank_x_account_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 10001 | 1 | SAVING | 111 | A | 901 |
| 50 | 10002 | 1 | SAVING | 111 | A | 902 |
| 80 | 10006 | 1 | SAVING | 111 | A | 906 |
| 80 | 10007 | 1 | SAVING | 111 | A | 907 |

Answer (score 0):

To start with you are doing your join between Account and Account x Bank based on account_key and you have two rows in Account x Bank with account_key = 50 so for the row in Account that has account_key = 50 you will get two rows after your join. And the same with the Account that has account_key = 80.

Is there anything more that you can use in that join to distinguish the rows in Account x Bank better?